# Get device model with UIAutomation?

Tags: ios, instruments, ios-ui-automation

Is there a way to get the device type (e.g. `iPhone 6`) or model (e.g. `iPhone7,2`) from within the UIAutomation JavaScript framework? Closest I’ve come is:

```
UIATarget.localTarget().model()
```

which gives me `iPhone Simulator` or `iPad`, etc. It’s too generic.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen a way to specifically determine model when running the simulator. However you can dig out if you are on iPhone/Pad sim/device as well as the OS version number this information should ideally be enough for you to properly map out your tests.

```
var targetDevice =  UIATarget.localTarget();
UIALogger.logMessage("iOS System name: " + targetDevice.systemName());
UIALogger.logMessage("iOS Version number: " + targetDevice.systemVersion());
UIALogger.logMessage("Target name: " + targetDevice.name());
UIALogger.logMessage("Model name: " + targetDevice.model());
```

Running this on an iPhone 6 simulator produces

```
2014-10-01 21:14:35 +0000 Default: iOS System name: iPhone OS
2014-10-01 21:14:35 +0000 Default: iOS Version number: 8.0
2014-10-01 21:14:35 +0000 Default: Target name: iPhone Simulator
2014-10-01 21:14:35 +0000 Default: Model name: iPhone Simulator
```

The [UIATarget reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Reference/UIATargetClassReference/index.html#//apple_ref/javascript/instm/UIATarget/tapWithOptions) is where I found those functions.